# How to Reference an instance of an object when "use strict"; has been declared?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, instance, strict

I have created an object and instanciated it.

When I want to access its members (properties, attributes...) an error message is issued.

How to solve the problem ?

See the errors on the code as comments.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";
  var v = 25;

  var dObj = function(){
      var v = 100;
      var f=(function(){
           console.log("Insiding...")
      })();
      console.log(v); // v locale
      console.log(window.v); // v globale.
  }

  var iObj = dObj();

 // THE ERROR LAYS HERE //
 // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v'
 // of undefined at this.html:19 [YANDEX]
  console.log(iObj.v);

 // And Here too. TypeError:
 // iObj is undefined this.html:22:1 [FIREFOX]
 iObj.f();
 </script>
```

Comment: I don't think that error depends on `"use strict"` at all.  The `dObj` function does not return anything, so `iObj` is indeed undefined.

Comment: Can you explain with a concrete example please ?

Comment: Posted an answer, is that enough explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword in Javascript declares a variable; it does not declare or assign properties of any object.  It looks like what you wanted to write this:

```
var dObj = function () {
  return {
    v: 100,
    f: function(){
      console.log("Insiding...")
    },
  };
};
```

When you call a function, for example `dObj()`, the value of the function invocation is the "return value" of the function, i.e. the expression next to the first `return` statement inside the function.  Here, that is an object literal, which has two properties, `v` and `f`.

---

In your original code, `"use strict";` enables strict mode, which is actually not the cause of the error.  Then `var v = 25;` declares a variable `v`, which is actually never used.  Then you have the following definition of `dObj`:

```
var dObj = function(){
  var v = 100;
  var f=(function(){
       console.log("Insiding...")
  })();
  console.log(v); // v locale
  console.log(window.v); // v globale.
}
```

This declares a function `dObj` that, when called, does the following things.  It creates a local variable `v` (hiding the `v` created earlier) and sets its value to 100.

Then it creates another local variable `f` and sets it equal to the return value of the IIFE ("immediately-invoked function expression") `(function() { console.log("Insiding...")})()` - which is `undefined`.  This IIFE also outputs "Insiding..." to the console.  In other words, that code does not make `f` a function.  Instead, it evaluates an anonymous function (here outputting "Insiding...") and makes `f` its return value (here `undefined`).

Then it outputs the local variable `v`, outputting 100.

Last, it outputs `window.v`, which is `undefined`.  (If you had written `window.v = 25` earlier, you would be assigning a new property of the `window` object, so this would then output `25` instead of `undefined`.  It is also true that `window` is the global object in the browser, so the same effect as `window.v = 25` would be achieved if you had not written `"use strict"` and had written `v = 25` with no `var`, but doing that is all kinds of messy, so you're right to use "use strict".)

```
var iObj = dObj();
```

This sets `iObj` to the return value of your `dObj` function, which is `undefined` because there is no `return` statement.  However, `dObj` does run to completion: namely it outputs `Insiding...`, `100`, and `undefined`.

Last, you've got two statements that both throw errors:

```
console.log(iObj.v);
iObj.f();
```

These both throw errors because `iObj` is undefined and has no properties to speak of.